# Button in form event always returning false

Tags: javascript, forms

So I have a form, a id and password and a button for submit, when the user fills it out and submit with the button, there is a function checking if id matches password. but it always return false in the function. why? Here is the code:

```
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="ID" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <button id="but" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Enter Workspace</button>
    </form>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#but').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            console.log("in function");
            var ID=$('input[name=u]').val();
            var password = $('input[name=p]').val();
            if(personnel[ID]){
                if(personnel[ID].password === password){
                    window.open("Workspace/index.html");
                }
                else{
                    alert("Incorrect ID Or Password")
                }

            }
            else{
                alert("Incorrect ID Or Password")
            }
        });
    });
```

var personnel is in another script,

```
<script src="L/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which `if()` is failing, `if(personnel[ID])` or `if(personnel[ID].password === password)`?

Comment: How is your data stored? is the personnel a object or an array? do they type in a string into the id? or is it a number?

Comment: show us the contents of the other script

Comment: the first if is failing. if(personnel[ID]) is failing. this is part of the other script since it's just repeating.

var personnel={
 "I000001":{
  "password":125827
 },
 "I000002":{
  "password":192374
  
 },
 "I000003":{
  "password":197292
    
 },
 "I000004":{
  "password":193287
    
 },
 "I000005":{
  "password":142823
  
 },
 "I000006":{
  "password":192373
  
 },
 "I000007":{
  "password":192834
  
 },
 "I000008":{
  "password":123241
  
 },
 "I000009":{
  "password":192392
  
 },
 "I000010":{
  "password":200029
  
 },

Comment: @Barmar, answered ur question in my last commend

Comment: @J.doe Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your passwords are numbers, but `.val()` returns a string. And you're using strict comparison with `===`, so it doesn't coerce the types.

You should change the passwords to strings in `personnel`.

```js
var personnel = {
  "I000001": {
    "password": "125827"
  },
  "I000002": {
    "password": "192374"
  },
  "I000003": {
    "password": "197292"
  },
  "I000004": {
    "password": "193287"
  },
  "I000005": {
    "password": "142823"
  },
  "I000006": {
    "password": "192373"
  },
  "I000007": {
    "password": "192834"
  },
  "I000008": {
    "password": "123241"
  },
  "I000009": {
    "password": "192392"
  },
  "I000010": {
    "password": "200029"
  },
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#but').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("in function");
    var ID = $('input[name=u]').val();
    var password = $('input[name=p]').val();
    if (personnel[ID]) {
      if (personnel[ID].password === password) {
        alert("Password is correct");
      } else {
        alert("Incorrect Password");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Incorrect ID");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="u" placeholder="ID" required="required" />
<input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
<button id="but" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Enter Workspace</button>
```